# issue adding values to an array

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack, angular-forms

i have an interface as follows:

```js
   import {IRecipients} from "./irecipients";    export interface IDataProcessingSpecification {
 user:string;
 businessID:string;
 recipient:IRecipients[];
   }
```

th IRecipient is the following :

```js
   export interface IRecipients {
   
 recipientName:string,
 recipientLocation:string[]
   }
```

and here i have initialized a variable of type    IDataProcessingSpecification :

```js
   generatedDataProcessing:IDataProcessingSpecification=
   {
     user:'',
     businessID:'',
   
     recipient:[{recipientName:'',recipientLocation:[]}],
   
   }
```

The recipients are one or more. to implement which I have followed    this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2) that is to allow one or more recipients. so a    recpient contains two controls a textbox for name and a checkbox for    location.
       when user pick one location from the checkbox, following code will be    run:

```js
onRecipientLocation(event,location,i) {
   console.log("here " + location+ "  " + i )
   if (event.target.checked) {
   
     this.generatedDataProcessing.recipient[i].recipientLocation.push(location)
   
     console.log("location "+ i+ this.generatedDataProcessing.recipient[i].recipientLocation)
   }
   }
   
 }
```

so, for the first recipient the checkbox function works ok, but when add another control by clicking add, i receive this error "Cannot read property 'recipientLocation' of undefined", while selecting from checkbox

**EDIT** here is the HTML code:

```
    <div *ngFor="let address of dataProcessingForm.controls.linktodrive.controls; let i=index">
    <div>
      <span>Name the recipient: </span>
      <span *ngIf="dataProcessingForm.controls.linktodrive.controls.length > 1">

        <a (click)="removeLink(i)">    Remove </a></span>
    </div>

    <!-- Angular assigns array index as group name by default 0, 1, 2, ... -->
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input type="text" placeholder="*Enter Recipient" formControlName="recipientName">

      <div>
        <label for="recipientLocation"><h3> Recipient Location:</h3> </label>
          <div *ngFor="let obj of recipientLocation">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="recipientLocation"
                   formControlName="recipientLocation"
                   value="{{obj}}"
                   (change)="onRecipientLocation($event,obj,i)"
            >
            {{obj}}
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>

  </div>

    <div><a  (click)="addLink()"> Add </a></div>
```

Comment: None of your snippets has runnable code. Please do not misuse snippets for formatting purposes only.

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML from your template as well? I'm guessing the issue is that `i` falls outside the bound of your `recipient` array.

Comment: add the html who makes the call to onRecipientLocation

Comment: I have added the HTML code

Comment: @user184994 not sure what you mean? the i will be incremented whenever i add a new recipient control. and i used it in my code to define which recipient has been clicked

Comment: `i` is defined in the `ngFor` in the first line of that HTML template (`let i = index`), and then passed in to the `onRecipientLocation` function from the template.

Comment: @user184994, yes, so what is wrong with this? and why in the second recipient control i got the error

Comment: Are you able to create a Stackblitz that reproduces the error?

Comment: what is a Stackblitz ?

Comment: An free online VS Code IDE that you can use to demonstrate the issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkbzju

Answer (score 0):

Probably because even though `i` value get incremented `recipient` has only one object. try to push to  `0` index or add an if condition before push

```
if( this.generatedDataProcessing.recipient[i]){
  this.generatedDataProcessing.recipient[i].recipientLocation.push(location)
 }
```

Comment: no i cannot do this, because, I may have more than one recipient. so I want to specify which recipient

Comment: the same happened